# Meteor load template upon selection of dropdown list option

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor

I have a dropdown list generated via this template, located in `ranvas.html`:

```
<template name="shape-dropdown">
    <select id = "shape-select">
        <option value = "none">select a shape</option>
        {{#each shape in shapes}}
            <option value = "{{this}}"> {{this}} </option>
        {{/each}}
    </select>
</template>
```

Which gets the shape names from a helper in `ranvas.js`:

```
 Template.shape-dropdown.helpers({
      shapes: [
          { shapetype: "random line"},
          { shapetype: "random quadratic curve"},
          { shapetype: "random bezier curve"},
          { shapetype: "random arc"},
          { shapetype: "random stroke triangle"},
          { shapetype: "random fill triangle"},
          { shapetype: "random stroke rectangle"},
          { shapetype: "random fill rectangle"}
          { shapetype: "random stroke circle"},
          { shapetype: "random fill circle"},
      ]
  });
```

When one of those shapes is selected, I want a template located in `shape-templates.html` to load. 
For example when the "random line" option is selected, I want this template to load:

```
<template name="rand_line">
   <label>x1: <input type="text"> - <input type="text"></label>
   <label>y1: <input type="text"> - <input type="text"></label>
   <label>x2: <input type="text"> - <input type="text"></label>
   <label>y2: <input type="text"> - <input type="text"></label>
   {{> rand_strokeStyle}}
</template>
```

Comment: You can use the [Dynamic](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/blaze-dynamic-template-includes/) template helper with a reactive variable that is set from the dropdown's `change` event handler.

Comment: Are you using Iron Router?

Comment: @StefanL19 No, I'm not

Comment: Did you try to use Sessions?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use [dynamic templates](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_dynamic)

```
{{> Template.dynamic template="rand_line"}}
```

If you extend your `.shape-dropdown.helpers` you can track the 1:1 matching template for each shape, ex:

```
Template.shape-dropdown.helpers({
  shapes: [
    { shapetype: "random line", template: "rand_line"},
    ...
  ]
});
```

You'll need an event handler to track the selection:

```
Template.shape-dropdown.events({
  'change #shape-select": function(ev){
  var tpl = shapes.filter(function ( obj ) {
    return obj.shape === $('#shape-select').val();
  })[0].template;
  Session.set('template',tpl)
  }
});
```

Then of course you still need a helper to get the value of that session variable into your blaze template as a parameter to the dynamic helper.

Comment: How do I get the template to change based on the option?  Would I use `{{#let}}` and have a variable that points to the template object in the helper?

Comment: You'll want an event handler to update a Session variable or reactive var and have the dynamic template point to that. I'll augment the answer.